# Git Status Not Showing Any Pending Commits

Tags: git, github, version-control

1. I created a branch from develop branch say 'hotfix-issue#4',
2. I worked on this new hotfix branch.
3. commit changes to hotfix branch.
4. Checkout develop branch.
5. Merge changes to develop branch.
6. Type git status to check repo status, but I got following message

On branch develop
nothing to commit, working directory clean

Though I know there are commits pending to push.

One more unusual thing happen here:

1. I go to server where my application reside.
2. Pull the changes from develop branch.
3. After pull, If here I type git status, it says there are some commits pending and then on pushing these commits it says Everything is up to date.
4. Now git status says nothing to commit, working directory clean.

Note: I created develop branch locally and then push it to origin and hence pull it to server later.

Comment: Look at your `git log`

Comment: Yes in git log it is showing that commit.